# How do I check if the id or the class name given to an HTML element is ever being used by a script or a stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, dreamweaver

I'm editting someone else idiotically written code and a separate id and class name is given to many elements that I doubt if is even used, ever. I want to check if the id or class name given to any element is ever used.

Can I do that in Dreamweaver, or any other IDE for that matter?

Comment: yep, just copy the ID/Class Name and perform a "find" in the CSS/html  file

Comment: Google Chrome has an audit feature that will report unused CSS classes.

Comment: @GrowinMan «someone else idiotically written code» is bad form IMO. The reasons are: blaming someone else sounds like an excuse; it doesn't add useful information; it decreases the signal-to-noise ration of the question; it's pointlessly aggressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Google Chrome has an audit feature that will report unused CSS classes.

[unused-css.com](http://unused-css.com/) also attempts to provide a tool to detect unused CSS although the site must be publicly available.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know the possibilities of Dreamweaver, but a full text search on your whole codebase may be a basic method that could always work.

If you like command line solutions you could resort to grep, perl, findstr or whatever you are comfortable with.

Comment: Full text search wouldn't help I was importing from multiple CSS files.